# Click event works on single click first time needs double click every other time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 buttons that shows a small div on a table. When they are hit the first time one click it opens up the modal and when a selection is made closes the modal. After the modal is closed it takes a double click to reopen the modal. Im sure its probably something simple im just missing.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#@additionalButtonID,#@additionalButtonID2,#@additionalButtonID3").on("click", function (e) {
                $ClickedItem = $(this);
                $("div#@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier").css("left", e.clientX - 150);
                $("div#@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier").css("top", e.clientY);
              
                $("div#@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier").fadeIn(200, function () {
                    $(document).on("click", function (e) {                      
                        if (!e.target.classList.contains("additionalButtons")) {
                            $("div#@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier").hide();
                        }
                    });
                })
        });
    });
   
    $(".btn-tbl-buttons").on("click", function () {        
        $("div#@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier").hide();
    });

    $(".list-tbl-items").on("click", function (e) {
        if ((e.target).querySelector('button') != null) {
            (e.target).querySelector('button').click();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

updated

```
<script>
let divIsFadedIn = false;

$("#@additionalButtonID, #@additionalButtonID2, #@additionalButtonID3").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // prevent the event from propagating up to the document element
  const div = $("div#div-@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier");
    $("div#div-@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier").css("left", e.clientX -150);
    $("div#div-@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier").css("top", e.clientY);
  div.fadeIn(200);
});
    
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).next("div#div-@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier, div#div-@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier  *").length) {
    $("div#div-@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier").fadeOut(200);
  }
});

   
    $(".btn-tbl-buttons").on("click", function (e) {
        $("div#div-@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier").fadeOut(200);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(".list-tbl-items").on("click", function (e) {
        if ((e.target).querySelector('button') != null) {
            (e.target).querySelector('button').click();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
</script>
this is where i got.
```

Answer (score 0):

This section embedded within the three buttons `.click()` attaches a new event handler over and over again. I don't know if this is intended, you might want to call it `.off()` each time, or use `.one()` to only attach for the next event. I presume this is firing adjacent to your `fadeIn()` so the `div#@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier` is being both hidden and faded in simultaneously. I'd like to see it in action to understand better.

```
                $(document).on("click", function (e) {                      
                    if (!e.target.classList.contains("additionalButtons")) {
                        $("div#@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier").hide();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I would love ot use off. But if i do it just turns it off after the first attempt. Which is obviously not what I am looking for. Unless im misunderstanding something here. (which is likely).

Comment: most definitely not intended. HOw would i initialize those button clicks just once? and stil lhave them clickable multiple times later.

Comment: The issue is those 3 buttons need to be able to be used multiple times to open the small popup div.